# Epiphany GNOME Web Browser 2.28.0 hangs when Japanese date renders

Tags: javascript, java, linux, fonts, epiphany

This is one of the weird issue I am facing right now.

This is regarding a touch device based on Arm processor and developed in Java 1.6. 
This device has Japanese and Chinese language supported. In one of the part of device shows the current date(developed in java script). When device switches to Japanese language sometimes (infact very often) it is observed that device gets frozen.
After a lot of research a pattern is found that is "At the time of Japanese Date rendering causes this issue". For a test I disabled rendering date and observed no freeze.

No clue how its happening.

**Below are few details:**

```
Epiphany version: 2.28.0
Java version: 1.6
Japanese font used: STXihei.ttf, HirakakuW3.otf, FHDaHei.ttf and HirakakuW6.ttf
```

What I am looking for:

1. Is Japanese fonts are causing the issue.
2. Is the epiphany version has any specific issues.
3. Why only rendering current Date is causing this issue. (Other static strings also displaying well in the front panel of the device without any issue)

   Date format : 2016 2 月 17 水曜日

Any idea or thoughts are welcome.

The question may need more information. Please feel free to ask as it is impossible to give all the information in a single attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change bit per pixel value of your Xorg, Try to tweak some values between 32 bpp to 24 bpp, 24 bpp has resolved our issue.

Comment: Thank you.. I am glad to hear that. @vivek